# Plotting a Discrete Bar chart using nvd3 directive

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a JSON data of this format:

```
[{"key":"A","values":187},{"key":"B","values":110}]
```

Can any ne help me to plot a bar chart using nvd3?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples on the Internet...
Here is just one: http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html
And another one: http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBarHorizontal.html

You can take the source code from there, and add your data instead of the example data there.

Hope this helps you...